# Concise way to set input directory

Tags: machine-learning, files-and-directories

Got this Mathematica ResNet- 50 Code online and has been trying to make run it using the same data set but it seems my directories to the dataset were not correct, keep getting this error:

```
In[35]:= feats = RandomSample[feats];
Length@feats
RandomSample::lrwl: The set of items to sample from, 
Join[normalFeats,virusFeats,bacFeats], should be a non-empty list or a rule 
weights -> choices.
Out[36]= 1
```

and at the TrainNet I encountered this:

```
In[20]:= trainedNet = 
NetTrain[learnNet, trainFeat, ValidationSet -> testFeat, 
MaxTrainingRounds -> 35, TargetDevice -> "GPU"]

NetTrain::jitgen: Generator function cannot be used when the net to be 
trained has not been fully specified.

NetTrain::nfspec: Cannot train net: input of first layer is not fully 
specified.

Out[20]= $Failed
```

Here is the full Code 
    NotebookDirectory[]

```
"C:\\Users\\El_Elyon`s\\Desktop\\prj\\"

SetDirectory["/Users/El_Elyon`s/Desktop/prj/"]

"C:\\Users\\El_Elyon`s\\Desktop\\prj"
```

Importing Raw Pictures

```
normalFiles = FileNames[Except["."] ~~ "*.jpeg", NotebookDirectory[] <> 
"train/NORMAL"];

virusFiles =FileNames[Except["."] ~~ "*_virus_*.jpeg", 
NotebookDirectory[] <> "train/PNEUMONIA"];
bacFiles =FileNames[Except["."] ~~ "*_bacteria_*.jpeg", 
  NotebookDirectory[] <> "train/PNEUMONIA"];

normalImg = Import /@ normalFiles;

virusImg = Import /@ virusFiles;

bacImg = Import /@ bacFiles;

ClearAll[cropFinder];
cropFinder[x_, img_] := Module[{mid, flatValues, cropLeft, cropRight},
mid = Ceiling[Last[ImageDimensions[img]]/(x)];
flatValues = 
Flatten@ImageData[ImageTake[ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"], {mid, mid}]];
cropLeft = LengthWhile[flatValues, # < 0.16 &];
cropRight = LengthWhile[Reverse[flatValues], # < 0.16 &];
List[cropLeft, cropRight]
]

ClearAll[widthResize];
widthResize[img_] := 
Block[{ flatValues, cropLeft, cropRight, meanLeft, meanRight, list1, list2, 
list3, list4, list5, resizedImage},
list1 = cropFinder[10, img];
list2 = cropFinder[2, img];
list3 = cropFinder[4, img];
list4 = cropFinder[1.5, img];
list5 = cropFinder[1, img];
meanLeft = meanLeft /. x_ /; x > 300 :> 0;
meanLeft = -(Max[{list1[[1]], list2[[1]], list3[[1]], list4[[1]], 
   list5[[1]]}]);
meanRight = meanRight /. x_ /; x > 300 :> 0;
meanRight = -((Max[{list1[[2]], list2[[2]], list3[[2]], list4[[2]], 
    list5[[2]]}]));
resizedImage = ImagePad[img, {{meanLeft, meanRight}, {0, 0}}];
ImageResize[resizedImage, {512, 512}]
]

normNorm = 
ConformImages[
Table[If[RandomReal[] > .8, 
 If[RandomReal[] > .5, rotateImage[i], shearImage[i]], i], {i, 
 normalImg}], {512, 512}];
virusNorm = 
ConformImages[
Table[If[RandomReal[] > .8, 
 If[RandomReal[] > .5, rotateImage[i], shearImage[i]], i], {i, 
 virusImg}], {512, 512}];

bacNorm = ConformImages[
Table[If[RandomReal[] > .8, 
 If[RandomReal[] > .5, rotateImage[i], shearImage[i]], i], {i, 
 bacImg}], {512, 512}];
```

Initializing and Configuring Neural Net

```
RayNet = NetModel["ResNet-50 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"]

NetChain[ <> ]

In[3]:= FixedNet = NetTake[RayNet, 23]

Out[3]= NetChain[ <> ]

In[4]:= AdjustedNet = 
NetReplacePart[FixedNet, "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {512, 512}}]]

Out[4]= NetChain[ <> ]

In[5]:= learnNet = NetChain[{
DropoutLayer[0.3],
LinearLayer[3],
SoftmaxLayer[]
},
"Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1, 2}}]
]

Out[5]= NetChain[ <> ]
```

Preparing Images/Training  the Net

```
normalFeats = AdjustedNet[normNorm, TargetDevice -> "GPU"];

virusFeats = AdjustedNet[virusNorm, TargetDevice -> "GPU"];

bacFeats = AdjustedNet[bacNorm, TargetDevice -> "GPU"];

In[33]:= feats = Join[Map[# -> 0 &, normalFeats], Map[# -> 1 &, virusFeats], 
Map[# -> 2 &, bacFeats]];

In[35]:= feats = RandomSample[feats];
Length@feats

In[35]:= RandomSample::lrwl: The set of items to sample from, 
Join[normalFeats,virusFeats,bacFeats], should be a non-empty list or a rule 
weights -> choices.

Out[36]= 1

trainFeat = feats[[1 ;; 5000]];

testFeat = feats[[5000 ;;]];

In[20]:= trainedNet = 
NetTrain[learnNet, trainFeat, ValidationSet -> testFeat, 
MaxTrainingRounds -> 35, TargetDevice -> "GPU"]

In[20]:= NetTrain::jitgen: Generator function cannot be used when the net to 
be trained has not been fully specified.

In[20]:= NetTrain::nfspec: Cannot train net: input of first layer is not 
fully specified.

Out[20]= $Failed``
```

ResNet-50 was successfully loaded from the internet, as I said earlier I feel the network is not being able to find the datasets in the directory to train it can someone help me out on how to get this code run properly?

Comment: The error message *"Generator function cannot be used when the net to be 
trained has not been fully specified."* sounds like the net isn't fully specified. You can try the `NetInitialize` the net, then feed it some input samples. If it returns a well-formed result, the net should be ok.

Comment: OK will try that out immediately. Thanks @Niki Estner